# Property strongly type to loosely typed JSON serialize

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

I'm working on a MVC project using C# and have controller method that returns a JsonResult model. The model contains a property called Value.

Based on certain conditions the Value maybe a string value such as "C" or "N". But under other conditions it maybe .5.

When serializing the Model is it possible to check and if the property is a numeric to serialize it as number (no quotes)? If it is not a number then make it a string (quotes)?

For example I have the following class:

```
public class Answer
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I return a list of these back: I'd like to have something like below: (Notice the 1st answer the "value" is not quoted; however, the 2nd and 3rd answer are quoted.

```
{
    "answers": [
        {
           "id": 1,
           "value": .5 <- No quote here.
        },
        {
           "id": 1,
           "value": "C" <- Quote here
        },
        {
           "id": 1,
           "value": "N" <- Quote here
        }
     ]
}
```

When it comes back server side (de-serializing), I'd just like the string representation.

Comment: Did you test your own solution? It should work I think.

Comment: Yes, I have tested the results, Since Value is a string on the model, when it's serialized, it is ".5" instead of just .5

Comment: That's how strings are represented in C#, it's value is .5 only.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's when sending it to the client I want to conditionally "quote" it. If the string Value isnumeric, no "quotes" else I want it quoted. I apologize if it wasn't clear what I was trying to do. Right now, it quotes every value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to implement a custom JSON Converter. See the following link:

http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/CustomJsonConverter.htm